# Strange behavior in Scala Parallel View

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

According to Scaladoc,

> A view is a lazy version of some collection. Collection transformers such as map or filter or ++ do not traverse any elements when applied on a view. Instead they create a new view which simply records that fact that the operation needs to be applied.

That means the operations won't be applied until the elements is accessed. But how about Parallel ?

Take a look at this example:

```
def tn = Thread.currentThread.getName
val strList = List("I", "am", "a" , "student", ".", "I", "come", "from", "China", ".","I","love","peace")
val pvs = strList.par.view.filter{ s => println("f "+ tn); s == "I"}.map{s => println("m " + tn); s.toLowerCase}
```

The second will print out like the following :

[image]

When you apply `foreach` on `pvs` , it outputs : 
 [image]

I can't understand why the performance of  **Parallel** style is not the same as the normal one :

```
val strList = List("I", "am", "a" , "student", ".", "I", "come", "from", "China", ".","I","love","peace")  // or read from a text file , e.g. article.txt 
strList.view.filter{s => println("f");  s == "I"}.map{s => println("m"); s.toLowerCase}.foreach(s => println("p"))
```

Comment: Please provide text per cut'n'paste, if possible, not images. Btw.: What is `tn`, Thread name?

Comment: Downvoted because of the images were copy&pasted text would have been much better.

Answer (score 1):

Because the interpreter evaluates the expression by forcing it if the expression is a parallel collection view, so that it could print it (in essence, forces the view). Try either running this as a standalone Scala program, or do this:

```
scala> object foo { var bar: AnyRef = null }

scala> foo.bar = strList.par.view.filter{ s => println("f "+ tn); s == "I"}.map{s => println("m " + tn); s.toLowerCase}
```

EDIT:

Another issue above is the `filter` method on parallel views - unlike regular views, it is implemented by forcing the collection. This means that the moment you call `filter` on the parallel `view`, the entire filtered collection will be forced into an array and the predicate associated with the filter will have to be called. Methods like `groupBy` do the same thing on regular views.

Comment: The point of the example is that if you deny the interpreter to print the expression on the right hand side (which is a parallel view) by assigning the parallel view expression to a field in some object, the interpreter will not evaluate the view by calling `force`. So, the forcing does not happen when you call `filter` and `map` - it only happens in the interpreter because it needs to print the view. This is because the interpreter treats the collection views specially (avoids `force`), but it wasn't special-cased to treat parallel collection views in the same way as well. An oversight :)

Comment: Excuse me, you example is not parallel view

Comment: The interpreter does not have any special case for visualizing collections - the interpreter always calls `toString` to pretty-print the given value, but `toString` has different implementations.